# How to get an attribute from selected data item in Webix combo?

Tags: javascript, templates, combobox, webix

I have the following Webix combo:

```
{
  view: "combo", 
  label: 'Select the name',
  labelWidth:130,
  options: {
    data:[
      { itemId:"120", itemName:"Name 1"},
      { itemId:"121", itemName:"Name 2"}
    ],
    body: { template: '#itemName#' }        
  },
  on:{
    onChange:function(id){ alert(id) }
  }
}
```

It looks just as needed, but how can I get `itemId` after selecting new item? I can only get the auto-generated ID

The same code in a snippet:

http://webix.com/snippet/3a431f1c

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the object of the combobox and then you can get data of the selected item with the help of its getItem() method as:

```
var obj = this.getPopup().getBody().getItem(newValue);  //the object
var id = obj.itemId;  //the desired id which is itemId in your code
```

Please check the snippet [here](http://webix.com/snippet/f801772b).

Comment: Thank you! (: After double-checking the documentation found also `getList()` instead of `getPopup().getBody()`, but both work equally.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention that.But, you got the solution :)